# Transactional strategy for Hibernate L2 Cache

Tags: hibernate, second-level-cache

If Hibernate L2 cache vendor supports "transactional" strategy, then does it mean that this cache guarantees the same level of isolation between transactions as specified in Hibernate config?

For example, if cache supports "read-write" strategy then it guarantees REPEATABLE_READ isolation level (and in some cases only READ_COMMITTED level).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, tree-cache has it's own isolation level definition, so it is probably not using the Hibernate configuration.